# Changing text status depending on click in a ngfor dynamic list

Tags: javascript, angular

I have set up my project using angular 7. I have the list of data coming in an ngFor. I have my list of products that all have a status text of pending. If I click the approved or declined button it changes all the text in the list. To what ever I clicked. What I wanna do is if I click on one of the lists button I wanna change the status text from pending to either be Approved or Declined

I have tried getting the index value and using that, but it only works if I'm setting it from pending to Approve. Maybe my thinking is wrong on it!!

```
setStatus(product: any, index, status){
  if (product) {
      if(this.indexToAppendClassTo.indexOf(index) === -1)
        this.indexToAppendClassTo.push(index);
    } 
  if(status === 'approved'){
    this.approved.push(product)
  }else {
    this.declined.push(product)
  }
}
```

the `indexToAppendClassTo.includes(i)` will give you a boolean.

here is some code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1hsbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I want to be able to have the products pending and when I click on approve or decline it changes the value of Pending to Approve or Declined depending on the click.
Is there a better of doing this?

Comment: Plz elaborate mote. What does indexToAppendClassTo do?  If you want to just change status of a product from pending to either approved/declined, then why don't you do it with product object itself? Like:-  product.status = 'approved' and/or product.status='declined'.  etc.?

Comment: I've added this to a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1hsbn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I want the product to be pending. So when I click approve or decline it turns the pending text to either approve or declined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because we are dealing with array of objects you can easly toggle a property value with click event,  something like this `<p (click) ="product.status ='approved'">approve</p>`

*template*

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index" 
      [ngClass]="{'approved':product.status =='approved' ,'declined':product.status =='declined'}">
        <p>{{product.name}} <i>{{product.status}}</i></p> 
       <div>
          <p (click) ="product.status ='approved'">approve</p>
          <p (click) ="product.status = 'declined'">decline</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and in this way we move the toggle functionality to the template and very easy to style the element now with **[ngClass]** directive

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-csvyqp)

Answer (score 0):

So what i got to know from your code is that you have total three list.

one which you are using for iteration(ngFor) and other two are approved and declined correct me if i am wrong.

1 way is to use an object with your product and another key as status and change the value based on the button click.

or

add these lines to your code:

```
  if(status === 'approved'){
    //this line will remove the product from declined list
    this.declined = this.declined.filter(function(value, index, arr){

    return value!== product;

});
    this.approved.push(product)
  }else {
  //this line will remove the product from approved list
  this.approved= this.approved.filter(function(value, index, arr){

    return value!== product;

});
    this.declined.push(product)
  }
}
```

**Note:Make Sure you are displaying the result from proper list.**